# Finite Square Well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential

Let's say we have a potential given by:

$V(x) = 0$ if $x<0$

$V(x) = V_0$ if $0<x<a$

$V(x) = 0$ if $x>a$.

I understand how to solve the Schrödinger equation for $E_0>V$, however, when I have $0<E_0<V$ I came up with these solutions:

$\psi_1=Ae^{ik_1x}+Be^{-ik_1x}$

$\psi_2=Ce^{k_2x}+De^{-k_2x}$ and

$\psi_3=Fe^{ik_1x}+Ge^{-ik_1x}$

So, I thought I could eliminate $B$ from $\psi_1$ and $F$ from $\psi_3$ because they have non-physical solutions as their exponentials explodes when $x$ goes to $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, respectively, ending up with:

$\psi_1=Ae^{ik_1x}$

$\psi_2=Ce^{k_2x}+De^{-k_2x}$ and

$\psi_3=G^{-ik_1x}$

Is this correct or am I misunderstanding the real meaning behind the wave function?

Comment: That's not a square well - that's normally known as a square potential *step*. Wells go down, not up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incorrect. The exponential with imaginary argument does not explode, or even change magnitude. The elimination of one of the variables comes from some sort of boundary condition. For example, if waves are inbound from the left, then you'll have $G=0$, because $G$ corresponds to particles coming in from positive infinity. In this example, $A$ is the inbound wave, $B$ is the reflected wave, and $F$ is the transmitted wave. At most, you'll be able to solve for all but one of the variables with boundary conditions, and you won't be able to normalize the answer because plane waves like this aren't, strictly, normalizable. By tradition, you would normalize in terms of $A$.

Comment: Ok, I forgot that we could expand $e^{i\theta}$ in terms of sines and cosines and they wouldn't blow up, but let's say I had a term that did blow up by some reason, then I could eliminate that term?

Comment: Yes. That's what happens when you are finding bound state(s) of a square well instead of a step.